# How to squeeze an Array so no consective two or more values appear and is replace by that one value

Tags: java, arrays, oop, for-loop

```
 /**
     * squeeze() takes an array of ints. On completion the array contains the
     * same numbers, but wherever the array had two or more consecutive
     * duplicate numbers, they are replaced by one copy of the number. Hence,
     * after squeeze() is done, no two consecutive numbers in the array are the
     * same.
     * 
     * Any unused elements at the end of the array are set to -1.
     * 
     * For example, if the input array is [ 4 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 ], it
     * reads [ 4 , 1 , 3 , 1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 ] after squeeze() completes.
     * @param ints
     *            the input array.
     */
    public static void squeeze(int[] ints) {
         // TODO: Fill in your solution here. Ours takes linear time and is less than 10 lines long,
        // not counting blank/comment lines or lines already present in this file.
       // ArrayList<Integer> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

below is my code but for some reason the logic is not right, it returns the same array passed into the function and not the modified one, I believe most of the logic to be correct unless there is an error in the continue statement. Every time a consecutive same index appears in the array, it should be replaced by that one index

```
        int deleted = 0;
        int i = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j < ints.length; j++) {  ?
                if(ints[i] == ints[j]) {
                    deleted++;
                    continue;
                }else {
                    //k.add(ints[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            ints = new int[ints.length + deleted];
            for(int s = 0; s < ints.length; s++) {
                if(ints[s] == 0) {
                    ints[s] = -1;
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * main() runs test cases on your squeeze() method. Prints summary
     * information on basic operations and halts with an error (and a stack
     * trace) if any of the tests fail.
     */
```

Comment: Your function leaves the array unchanged because it creates a new array, and only makes any changes to that new array. Note that the function's return type is `void`, so it cannot work by creating and returning a new array.

Comment: The second loop actually fills the whole of the new array with -1 values, because new arrays are initially filled with 0.

Comment: The rest of the indices after `.length`? That is all of the indices, by definition.

Comment: @kaya3 you are correct, i thought `ints` was the parameter array. But it is redeclared.

Comment: Because you can't easily delete an element from an array, most implementations I've seen like this construct a new array to return as the result.  The algorithm is trivial.

Comment: When you use the continue keword does it shorten the size of the array or keep it the same size but left those indexes as 0?

Answer (score 0):

continue simply jumps to the end of your for loop skipping any code. that is, it starts the next interation.
as pointed out in the comments, you need to modify the array that was passed in since there is no return value in the defined method. 
Consider the following....

```
    int deleted = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < (ints.length-1); j++) {  
        if (ints[j] == -1) // if -1 then we've reached the end of the original list
            break; // this breaks out of the loop even if the constraint is not met

        if(ints[j] == ints[j+1]) { // if consecutive entries are equal
           // shift all values down in the list
           for (int k = j+1; k < (ints.length-1); k++){
               ints[k] = ints[k+1];
           } // end loop k

           // set the last entry in the array to -1 since we moved everything down
           ints[ints.length-1] = -1;

           //back our loop up one so that we stay where we were in case there was 
           // more than two consecutive numbers that were the same
           j--; 
        }
    } // end loop j

    // display the result
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
        System.out.print(ints[i] + ", " );
```